# SQL to get rows where a date time is 5 or less days away

Tags: sql, mysql

I tried this and it returned incorrect rows

```
SELECT `product_id`, `expiry` FROM `products_featured` 
WHERE `notified_expiry` = FALSE 
     AND `expiry` != 
    AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= `expiry`
```

I want to select all rows where the expiry date is within 5 days from now.

The rows returned were

```
    [0]=>   array(2) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(2) "26"
    ["expiry"]=>
    string(10) "2010-07-07" }

    [1]=>   array(2) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(2) "38"
    ["expiry"]=>
    string(10) "2010-07-24" }

    [2]=>   array(2) {
    ["product_id"]=>
    string(2) "39"
    ["expiry"]=>
    string(10) "2010-07-07" }
```

As you can see, only one of those rows is to occur within 5 days (assuming `NOW()` is returning `2010-07-22` which I have confirmed).

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: are you storing "expiry" as varchar? Why not as a date?

Comment: @Sjull I am storing as a `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `product_id`, `expiry` FROM `products_featured` WHERE `notified_expiry` = FALSE AND `expiry` != 0 AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) >= `expiry` AND NOW() <= `expiry`
```

Comment: It does not explain why your statement did not work. It's probably just selecting the rows with the part `NOW() <= expiry`. So an `expiry` of `2010-10-05` would pass although it shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 
    `product_id`, `expiry` FROM `products_featured` 
WHERE 
    `notified_expiry` = FALSE 
    AND `expiry` != 0 
    AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), `expiry`) BETWEEN 0 AND 5